# Back transformation of dependent variable after square-root transformation in a two-part model in MPlus

Tags: variance, data-transformation, back-transformation, mplus

I want to find out if one behavioral intervention had also an effect on another behavior (let´s say smoking). Currently, I am testing the moderation with a two-part model in MPlus, where smoking is the dependent outcome variable. Previous analyses suggested a square-root transformation of the terribly skewed data. In my research on back-transformation of the data, I found that simply squaring all transformed data was not enough, one should also add a correction factor including the variance of the transformed data:

https://influentialpoints.com/Training/transformations-principles-properties-assumptions.htm#squa

[image]

In my MPlus output, I don´t have any variances given because of the dependent nature of the variable, does anyone have an idea how to proceed here? I read that it´s difficult for confidence intervalls and means, so any help would be highly appreciated here!

Comment: Do you care about the detransformed mean and variance? You could do something like a bootstrap instead of a transformation if you do.

Comment: How does what you are doing in Mplus differ from a regression?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, Jeremy, and thank you so much for your quick response! Well, I would need the detransformed mean for the interpretation of the results (say the mean consumed cigarettes per day after the intervention) but the detransformed variance is not important for me, no. I will do some research on bootstrapping as an alternative method, thank you!

Comment: On the comment on MPlus and regression: I forgot do add this detail in the description, technically it does not differ much, but with the help of MPlus I am able to model latent growth curves, which handle incomplete data very well (two-year follow-ups) and show outcome growth trajectories very nicely. So it´s a two-part latent growth model I´m running here, using MPlus.